# How to make my font bold using css?

Tags: css

I'm very new to HTML and CSS and I was just wondering how I could make my font bold using CSS.

I have a plain HTML page that imports a CSS file, and I can change the font in the CSS. But I don't know how to make the font bold, can anyone help me?

Comment: I suggest that you read the CSS2 specification, it gives a very thorough explanation of what you can do and how to do it.  And it isn't too dry, either.  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/

Answer (score 299):

You can use the CSS declaration `font-weight: bold;`.

I would advise you to read the CSS beginner guide at http://htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/ .

Answer (score 78):

You can use [the `strong` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong) in html, which is great semantically (also good for screen readers etc.), which *typically* renders as bold text:

```html
See here, some <strong>emphasized text</strong>.
```

Or you can use [the `font-weight` css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) to style any element's text as bold:

```css
span { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph of <span>bold text</span>.</p>
```

Comment: I've put the whole 2nd paragraph in bold, so it's not emphasising the words "bold text", it's just style.

Comment: It's only great semantically if you are trying to emphasize something; if it's a style without trying to emphasize, the `<strong>` element is semantically misleading.

Answer (score 35):

You'd use `font-weight: bold`.

Do you want to make the entire document bold? Or just parts of it?

Answer (score 26):

Sine you are new to html here are three ready to use examples on how to use CSS together with html. You can simply put them into a file, save it and open it up with the browser of your choice:

This one directly embeds your CSS style into your tags/elements. Generally this is not a very nice approach, because you should always separate the content/html from design.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">     
    <head>      
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
        <title>Hi, I'm bold!</title>  
    </head>           
    <body>
        <p style="font-weight:bold;">Hi, I'm very bold!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The next one is a more general approach and works on all "p" (stands for paragraph) tags in your document and additionaly makes them HUGE. Btw. Google uses this approach on his search:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">     
    <head>      
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
        <title>Hi, I'm bold!</title>  
        <style type="text/css">
            p {
              font-weight:bold;
              font-size:26px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>   
    <body>
        <p>Hi, I'm very bold and HUGE!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

You probably will take a couple of days playing around with the first examples, however here is the last one. In this you finally fully seperate design (css) and content (html) from each other in two different files. stackoverflow takes this approach.

In one file you put all the CSS (call it 'hello_world.css'):

```
  p {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:26px;
  }
```

In another file you should put the html (call it 'hello_world.html'):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">     
    <head>      
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
        <title>Hi, I'm bold!</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hello_world.css" />  
    </head>       
    <body>
        <p>Hi, I'm very bold and HUGE!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps a little. To address specific elements in your document and not all tags you should make yourself familiar with the `class`, `id` and `name` attributes. Have fun!

Answer (score 14):

Use the CSS [`font-weight`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp) property

Answer (score 8):

```
Selector name{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Suppose you want to make bold for p element

```
p{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

You can use other alternative value instead of bold like

```
p{
 font-weight:bolder;
 font-weight:600;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
font-weight: bold
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<STYLE type="text/css">
   body
   {
      font-weight: bold;
   }
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
Body text is now bold.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 6):

font-weight: bold;

Answer (score -2):

You could use a couple approaches. First would be to use the strong tag

```
Here is an <strong>example of that tag</strong>.
```

Another approach would be to use the font-weight property. You can achieve inline, or via a class or id. Let's say you're using a class.

```
.className {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use a hard value for font-weight and most fonts support a value between 300 and 700, incremented by 100. For example, the following would be bold:

```
.className {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: Other Answers already covered these points. How does this Answer add value?