# Make certain characters or letters in object value bold react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets say I have an array of objects:

```
const options = [
 {
  text: "this is the text",
  description: "The word 'test' should be bold"
 },
 {
  text: "this is the text",
  description: "The word 'another-word' should be bold"
 }
]
```

the component renders something like this:

```
return (
  {
   options.map(option => {
    <p className="text-green-500">{option.description}</p>
  })
 }
)
```

Now I have to make the word/s "test" and "another-word" bold respectively. In some cases it has to only be characters inside a word.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make my font bold using css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991160/how-to-make-my-font-bold-using-css)

Comment: Im not exactly sure how that answers my question.

Comment: the jsx is just returning html, so structure it appropriately.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide proper context? The text rendered in the html is dynamic, I cant hard-code some css utility classes on certain text or characters.

Comment: See adiga's answer using `matchAll` – dynamically structure the HTML which is what I was indicating

Comment: can you just add a span or b element inside the options, and then just render it with `dangerouslySetinnerHtml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered it by replacing the value of description.
instead of:

```
description: "this is the text"
```

I changed it too:

```
description: <div>this is the <strong>text></strong></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a function which replaces the string in `''` with a `<b>` wrappers.

```
const highlight = (text) => text.replace(/'([^']+)'/g, "<b>$1</b>")
```

Then set the innerHTML like this:

```
return options.map(({ description }) => 
          <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: highlight(description) }}></p>
        )
```

You need to sanitize the string before doing this if these string are user inputs.

```js
const highlight = (text) => text.replace(/'([^']+)'/g, "<b>$1</b>")

function App() {
  const options = [{
      text: "this is the text",
      description: "The word 'test' should be bold"
    },
    {
      text: "this is the text",
      description: "The word 'another-word' should be bold"
    }
  ]
  
  return options.map(({ description }) => 
          <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: highlight(description) }}></p>
        )
};


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

You can avoid the innerHTML route entirely. In that case, you need split each string into fragments and then render them.

```
const highlight = (text) =>
  Array.from(text.matchAll(/([^']*)'*([^']*)'*([^']*)/g), ([m, p1, p2, p3]) =>
    m ? (
      <>
        {p1}
        <b>{p2}</b>
        {p3}
      </>
    ) : null
  );
```

And render it like this:

```
  return options.map(({ description }) => 
          <p>{highlight(description)}</p>
        )
```

Comment: @pilchard I haven't copied from anywhere. And I was just trying out the alternative which doesn't involve innerHTML and I've updated the answer with that.

Comment: That's fair, but still a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63037066/how-to-bold-specific-text-in-a-string-in-a-react-js-app).

Comment: The above regex fails for a substring which in between the delimiting single quotes features one or many escaped single quotes like e.g. [`'test\'s'`](https://regex101.com/r/4rnZ8A/1)

Comment: @PeterSeliger It highlights `test` as intended. OP hasn't mentioned anything about escaping `'` with a backslash

Comment: @adiga ... The comment is a generic one. It does not criticize but informs. One could also read it as hint to the OP to rethink the OP's use case and/or acceptance criteria.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably the easiest way to do it, just return a chunk of JSX from a function that deals with bolding the part of the text.

Stackblitz to run the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-gewz6v?file=App.tsx,index.tsx

```js
const options = [
    {
      text: 'this is the text',
      description: "The word 'test' should be bold",
    },
    {
      text: 'this is the text',
      description: "The word 'another-word' should be bold",
    },
  ];

  const boldText = (text) => {
    const termToBold = text.match(/'([^']+)'/)[1];
    const startIndex = text.toLowerCase().indexOf("'");
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {text.slice(0, startIndex)}
        <strong>
          {text.slice(startIndex, startIndex + 2 + termToBold.length)}
        </strong>
        {text.slice(startIndex + 2 + termToBold.length)}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {' '}
      {options.map((option) => {
        return <p className="text-green-500">{boldText(option.description)}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Only works when there's exactly one item in `''`

Comment: The above regex fails for a substring which in between the delimiting single quotes features one or many escaped single quotes like e.g. [`'test\'s'`](https://regex101.com/r/4rnZ8A/1)

Comment: @adiga ... _"It highlights test as intended. OP hasn't mentioned anything about ... [ ... ] – adiga"_ ... more than one word in between the quotes.

Comment: @adiga ... _"2) escaping of quotes is a very rare edge case"_ ... not taking care and / or being aware of escaped characters is the most common reason for breaking code if it comes to string parsing / evaluation.